# Post hoc pairwise comparison with continuous variable?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, lme4-nlme

My dependent variable is "mental health score" (discrete numeric, 1-10), and my independent variable is "dose" (continuous numeric, 0-500mg). I want to do a pairwise, post hoc analysis to see which dosage produces the highest mental health score, but I can't do this if my dependent variable is continuous; if I set "dose" as continuous numeric, then I can make prediction curves, but I can only do an anova on "dose," but cannot do a post hoc comparison to see which dose is most effective.

```
dose <- c(0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 250, 250, 250, 500, 500, 500)
df <- data.frame(mhs, dose)

mod <- lm(mhs ~ dose, data=df)
```

What analysis can I perform to be able to say, "XXXmg was associated with the highest mental health score?"

Comment: There is no pairwise comparison with continuous variables, but it's fine, you can do a linear model as you show in your code and get the slope for dose, which is arguably better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which dose provoked the largest response, you don't need any statistical analysis. Just look at the data or a graph of the data.

If you want help with choosing a statistical test, you'll need to articulate a question that can be answered by statistical calculations.

Answer (score 0):

With this type of outcome variable it would be wise to use ordinal logistic regression. [This page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/) shows one way to do that in R, with links to further reading about how to interpret the regression coefficients.

As you seem to expect a peak at an intermediate `dose` level and only seem to have a small set of `dose` levels, you could code `dose` as an unordered categorical predictor.* Then post-hoc tests comparing the regression coefficients for the different levels of `dose` will provide what you need. The [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) provides useful tools for such post-modeling analysis.

---

*With a large number of `dose` levels you could model `dose` flexibly and continuously, for example with regression splines, and plot model predictions (with confidence intervals) as a function of `dose`.